# Use a decorator to add in a variable to request

Tags: python, django

I know the suggested way to do this is middleware, but I'd like to implement the following to add in an `api_env` variable, accessed at run-time, so that my view can access it:

```
@api_wrapper
def my_view(request):
    print api_env     # this is the variable I want, such as request.epi_env
```

And the decorator:

```
def api_wrapper(func):
    def api_inner(request):
        request.api_env = 'something'
        return func(request)
    return api_inner
```

What's the best way to do this? I have about 100 functions to wrap so I don't want to add in a new parameter for every function but would just like to use the simplest approach to pass that 'env' variable. How should I do it.

Comment: If it is an env variable, Why don't you put it in your `settings.py`? What advantage do you wish to obtain by attaching some env into the request?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu it's an api variable environment. It's fetched at request-time.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable requirement. BTW, it seems your implementation is fine. Didn't that work?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I think it's immutable. Doing `request.GET = request.GET.copy()`; `request.GET['api_env'] = env` was ok though.

Comment: @carl.hiass: `request` is not immutable, `request.GET` is immutable. Why do you want to use `request.GET`? POST requests with a querystring are really "*odd*".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah, got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize this to work with an arbitrary number of positional and named parameters. Furthermore you might want to use [**`update_wrapper`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper), to add attributes like `csrf_exempt` to the "output" view, otherwise the `@csrf_except` will not be available in the outer function:

```
from functools import update_wrapper

def api_wrapper(func):
    def api_inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.api_env = 'something'
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    update_wrapper(api_inner, func, assigned=())
    return api_inner
```

That being said, this to some extent shows that using class-based views might be better in this case, since then one can define a *mixin*, and just mix it in the *method resolution order (MRO)* as a reusable component. In that case, one often do not have to take into account more complicated logic like the parameters, or the attributes that are added to the function, since a class-based view takes care of this itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def api_wrapper():
  def decorator(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def _wrapped_view(req, *args, **kwargs):
      req.env = 'something'
      return view_func(req, *args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped_view
  return decorator
```